# Converting an array to a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a  multi-dimensional array like this:

1 2 3

4 5 6

Now I need to convert this array into a string like `1,2,3;4,5,6`.

Can any one suggest how to do this, please?

Comment: I've fixed up your question a bit, but I don't understand (a) what you have, (b) how you want to transform it and (c) *what you've already tried*.

Answer (score 7):

simply use the `join` method on the array.

```
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].join(';')
'1,2,3;4,5,6'
```

It's lucky that you simply don't have to consider how the apply the join method on the inner lists, because  <strike>a list is joined by comma by default.</strike> when a list is coerced into a string, it by default uses commas to separate the items.

Comment: Just to further clarify here, join is not recursive. This is actually the same as calling [[1,2,3].toString(), [4,5,6].toString()].join(':'). This happens to work, for the trival example given.

Comment: but that array does not consistent the rows are dynamic one :(

Comment: @jordancpaul thanks for the heads-up :) Edited the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned by qiao, `join()` is not recursive.
But if you handle the recursion yourself you should acquire the desired result, although in a rather inelegant way.

```
var array = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7]];
    var result = [];

    array.forEach(
             function(el){
                 result.push(
                      el.join(",")
                 );
             });

    result.join(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serialize an array into a string and then deserialize it later to get an array from the string you might want to take a look at `JSON`:

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
array.toString();
```

See here for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp

- See answer by qiao for a much nicer approach to multidimensional arrays like this.

Comment: it was multi dimensional array

Comment: And i need to segregate the rows using semi colon

Comment: The solution by qiao will do that for your array... if you need a handling for a more complex array you should give 1-2 example of how the array can look like and how the result should look like then.